# WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly

Tags: android, nativescript, windows-subsystem-for-linux, android-sdk-tools, nativescript-cli

## Problem

Under Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) running `tns doctor` or any other `tns` command results with:

```
WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

1. Go to `android-sdk` on your system.
2. Rename `emulator/emulator.exe` to emulator.
3. Download platform-tools for linux (exact same version as for windows) and merge windows platform-tools with linux platform-tools.
4. Make sure you use proper version of java for NativeScript.
5. Make sure you properly set environmental variables in `.bashrc` under WSL (in my case):

```
export ANDROID_HOME='/mnt/d/Android/sdk'
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64'
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```